# Cannot set value for 2 fields at once using OData endpoint in CRM2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm modifying 2 fields on my custom entity, the first field is a lookup field which links to systemuser entity, the second field is simply a two options field.

This is the JSON data I send to Odata end point:

```
{
    "new_saleperson":
        {
            "__metadata": {"type":"Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.EntityReference"},
            "Id":"<My ID>",
            "LogicalName":"systemuser",
            "Name":"<My Name>"
        }
    ,"new_isenabled":true
}
```

And the header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
X-HTTP-Method: MERGE
```

However, I got the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <code>-2147220891</code>
    <message xml:lang="ja-JP">The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  To create the source, you need permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new source name is unique.  Inaccessible logs: Security.</message>
</error>
```

The strange thing is, if I update 1 field at a time, then everything goes as expected. In other word, the following JSON data can set new_saleperson field just fine:

```
{
  "new_saleperson": 
    {
        "__metadata": {"type": "Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.EntityReference"},
        "Id": "<My ID>",
        "LogicalName": "systemuser",
        "Name": "<My Name>"
    }
}
```

And the following JSON data can set new_isenabled to true without any problem:

```
{
   "new_isenabled":true
}
```

I even tried setting both fields at once, but let new_saleperson be null, and it works:

```
{
    "new_saleperson":
        {
            "__metadata": {"type":"Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.EntityReference"},
            "Id":null,
            "LogicalName":null,
            "Name":null
        }
    ,"new_isenabled":true
}
```

It just that setting both fields at the same time, with non-null value is causing error. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using Dynamic CRM 2011 on-premise.

Comment: maybe there is a plugin or something else that throw an exception when you set that two fields together?

Comment: Can you attempt to do the same update via an Excel import or IOrganizationService update?  Just want to see if it is somehow OData related

Comment: It is indeed due to a bug in one of my plugin, which only get triggered with this particular combination of user and flag value. I would delete this question but since there is already an answer, that's no longer seems to be and option.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your SalesPerson Id is not a valid system user? The system will throw an error if you use a GUID that doesn't exist.

Comment: That was the first thing I checked. But as I said, if I update just the salesperson field then everything is fine. Only if I update both salesperson and isenabled flag that things went wrong.